# Converting TSV file to JSON using text2json return no value

Tags: json, node.js, csv, testing, ava

I'm trying to convert a TSV file into JSON and write it to disk using [`text2json`](https://github.com/nilobarp/text2json).

#### Input data

There is an empty line at the end

```
U+2B695 shī
U+2B699 pū
U+2B6DB zhī
U+2B6DE jué
U+2B6E2 níng
U+2B6F6 chì
U+2B6F8 tí
```

#### Test

I've this test running with `ava`

```
import fs from "fs";
import test from "ava";
import jsonfile from "jsonfile";
import dataminer from "../src/dataminer";

test("extractPronunciation()", t => {
  const filepath = "src/codepoint-ruby.tsv";

  const data = dataminer.convertToJson(filepath, { separator: " " });

  t.is(data > 0);
});
```

#### Code

And this method based on [text2json](https://github.com/nilobarp/text2json):

```
import jsonfile from "jsonfile";
import text2json from "text2json";

export default {
  convertToJson: (filepath, options) => {
    const data = [];
    const parse = new text2json.Parser({ ...options, hasHeader: true });

    parse
      .text2json(filepath)
      .on("row", row => {
        data.push(row);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("Done >>>>>");
        return data;
      });
  },
};
```

#### Question

I see not trace of the `end` event being triggered, and the `convertToJson()` return nothing so my test fail, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

In your approach, you're filling the `data` array by reading asynchronously from a stream, instead of putting the whole file in memory and doing it synchronously. (And that's why you've got to use the `on` event to push data to your array).

This means that, in the same way you use

```
parse.text2json(filepath).on("row", row => {
      data.push(row);
});
```

you also need to use an `end` event to log the final result

```
parse.text2json(filepath)
    .on("row", row => {
        data.push(row);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Comment: the `end` event doesn't seem to be triggered in my case. I updated the question to provide more context

Comment: Yeah I saw you filed an issue. However, even if you tried the callback approach you wouldn't get a synchronous response. (you'd have to use the callback, of course). Now, regarding the "end" event not happening, you could -again- try the callback approach, or perhaps listen to the `error` event, as [the only exit point](https://github.com/nilobarp/text2json/blob/master/src/index.ts#L156) after reading the file must either callback or emit end.